# In R, finding the start and end dates for each interval after using diff()

Tags: r, date, diff

I am using diff() to find the difference in variables down a column. However, I would also like to display the dates the difference is found over.
For example:

```
Dates <- c("2017-06-07","2017-06-10","2017-06-15","2017-07-07","2017-07-12","2017-07-18")
Variable<-c(5,6,7,8,9,3)
dd<-diff(Dates)
dv<-diff(Variable)
```

I'd like to find a way to add columns for the start and end date for each interval, so  `"06-07"` as the start and `"06-10"` as the end date for the difference between the first 2 variables.  Any ideas?

Comment: It is not clear.  May be use `paste` i.e. `sprintf("06-07-%02d", diff(as.Date(Dates)))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I ask what you mean by "06-07-%02d" ? Is that supposed to represent the second date? Thanks.

Comment: It is just the format.  Based on your description (not clear on your post what the expected output might be) you may need some prefix part '06-07' and the difference of the 'Dates' (which I converted to 2 digit string with (`%02d`)

Comment: Okay, I will clarify. Your code finds the difference between surveys and pastes the result as days. There are three days between the first dates so the output is "06-07-03". Rather than that, I wanted a way to separate the start and end date into separate columns. So a column with "2017-06-07" and "2017-06-10". Basically I want these columns to show what dates `dd` is using.

Comment: Please update your post with the `expected output` you want.  It is much easier rather than describing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has requested *to add columns for the start and end date for each interval*.

This can be accomplished by using the `head()` and `tail()` functions:

```
# data provided by OP
Dates <- c("2017-06-07","2017-06-10","2017-06-15","2017-07-07","2017-07-12","2017-07-18")
Variable<-c(5,6,7,8,9,3)

start <- head(Dates, -1)   # take all Dates except the last one
end <- tail(Dates, -1L)    # take all Dates except the first one
dd <- diff(as.Date(Dates))   # coersion to class Date required for date arthmetic
dv <- diff(Variable)

# create data.frame of intervals
intervals <- data.frame(start, end, dd, dv)
intervals
```

> ```
>        start        end      dd dv
> 1 2017-06-07 2017-06-10  3 days  1
> 2 2017-06-10 2017-06-15  5 days  1
> 3 2017-06-15 2017-07-07 22 days  1
> 4 2017-07-07 2017-07-12  5 days  1
> 5 2017-07-12 2017-07-18  6 days -6
> ```

Note that `intervals` has 5 rows while the vector of breakpoints `Dates` it was constructed from has a length of 6.

Answer (score 0):

Are you after the difference in dates?

```
diff(as.Date(as.character(Dates,format="%Y-%M-%D")))
```